# How to draw a Sequence Diagram for a Use Case that <<extend >> another Use Case?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Can anyone provide any links that show how to draw this type of conditions?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Observer said, use a opt fragment AND a ref fragment inside.

- The opt fragment to set a piece of your sequence diagram as optional
- The ref fragment to delegate the content of the opt to another sequence diagram.

This way you have a 1-1 relationship between your use cases and your sequence diagrams, which is usually clearer.

See for example this picture : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/feb04/3101_figure11.jpg

Answer (score 2):

As you refer to a *sequence* diagram, you might be looking for the `opt` fragment: See an [example](http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/images/opt%20combined%20fragment.png). ([source](http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/))

That way you can conditionally include certain calls which are required by your `extend` use case.

[You'll find the opt fragment explained in more detail on the web.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html#N101A8)